# Use Published SSRS Report Model data in asp.net Webform Application

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, webforms

The reporting team in our organisation are using SSRS Report Models as the source of data for their SSRS reports. The Models are published to a reporting server.

I have some read-only pages on my asp.net web forms application which needs to use the same logic contained in these reports to present some of the data contained in them.

Is there a way to reference the published Report Models in my application? Can they be added as a datasource somehow? I want to avoid, if possible, having to write the same logic in my own application.

The asp.net web application is using dot net 4.0 VS2010 and the SSRS Report Models are using VS2008 deployed to a 2008 R2 Report Server.

Due to the variety of other data the website uses at the moment I am currently using a variety of data access methods (ado.net calls to SPs, entity framework, linq-to-sql etc.) so I am open to any methods to get at the Report Models.